# NodeJS API sync uploaded files through SFTP

Tags: node.js, rest, file-upload, sftp

I have a NodeJS REST API which has endpoints for users to upload assets (mostly images). I distribute my assets through a CDN. How I do it right now is call my endpoint /assets/upload with a multipart form, the API creates the DB resource for the asset and then use SFTP to transfer the image to the CDN origin's. Upon success I respond with the url of the uploaded asset.

I noticed that the most expensive operation for relatively small files is the connection to the origin through SFTP.

So my first question is:

**1. Is it a bad idea to always keep the connection alive so that I can 
always reuse it to sync my files.**

My second question is:

**2. Is it a bad idea to have my API handle the SFTP transfer to the CDN origin, should I consider having a CDN origin that could handle the HTTP request itself?**

Comment: Are you using Amazon AWS or just normal server?

Comment: Amazon AWS with CDN77

Comment: You should let the upload happen to S3, store the information in DB about the key/path. Then configure a automatic lambda invocation which would then upload the file to the CDN origin.

Comment: how do you deal with the url of the asset, it will ultimately be something like cdnurl.com/xx/assetname but until the lambda invocation uploads to the origin the asset won't be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: (1) it a not a bad idea to keep the connection alive, but it comes with complications. I recommend trying without reusing connections first. And (2) The upload should go through the API, but there maybe be ways to optimize how the API to CDN transfer happens.

Long Answer:

**1. Is it a bad idea to always keep the connection alive so that I can always reuse it to sync my files.**

It is generally not a bad idea to keep the connection alive. Reusing connections can improve site performance, generally speaking.

However, it does come with some complications. You need to make sure the connection is up. You need to make sure that if the connection went down you recreate it. There are cases where the SFTP client thinks that the connection is still alive, but it actually isn't, and you need to do a retry. You also need to make sure that while one request is using a connection, no other requests can do so. You would possibly want a pool of connections to work with, so that you can service multiple requests at the same time.

If you're lucky, the SFTP client library already handles this (see if it supports connection pools). If you aren't, you will have to do it yourself.

My recommendation - try to do it without reusing the connection first, and see if the site's performance is acceptable. If it isn't, then consider reusing connections. Be careful though.

**2. Is it a bad idea to have my API handle the SFTP transfer to the CDN origin, should I consider having a CDN origin that could handle the HTTP request itself?**

It is generally a good idea to have the HTTP request go through the API for a couple of reasons:

- For security reasons' you want your CDN upload credentials to be stored on your API, and not on your client (website or mobile app). You should assume that your code for website can be seen (via view source) and people can generally decompile or reverse engineer mobile apps, and they'll be able to see your credentials in the code.
- This hides implementation details from the client, so you can change this in the future without the client code needing to change.

@tarun-lalwani's suggestion is actually a good one - use S3 to store the image, and use a lambda trigger to upload it to the CDN. There are a couple of Node.js libraries that allow you to stream the image through your API's http request towards the S3 bucket directly. This means that you don't have to worry about disk space on your machine instance. 
Regarding your question to @tarun-lalwani's comment - one way to do it is to use the S3 image url path until the lambda function is finished. S3 can serve images too, if properly given permissions to do so. Then after the lambda function is finished uploading to the CDN, you just replace the image path in your db.

Comment: Thank you for your well thought answer, I'll go with (1) because @tarun-lalwani suggestion while good will be a bit of a hassle because I immediately attribute the ressource url to some ressources upon uploading and I would have to retrieve all of them uppon synchronization to the CDN because they are not necessarily done by refs to the db's asset object (for now).